# How can I check the existence of a key/file on an Amazon S3 Bucket using AWS iOS SDK v2?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-ios

I writing an iOS app that uploads and downloads files from an Amazon S3 bucket. I got said functionality working, but I need to write unit tests for it. Is there any way I can check if a file exists in my bucket so that I can confirm that it has been uploaded??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AWSS3` has a method called `- headObject:`. You can use it to see if the object exists in the bucket.

Comment: is there any reason to return null with headObject