# How to check file availability in S3 bucket

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services

i have integrated aws v1 sdk to in my ios application to upload videos in to S3 bucket in background mode using NSURLSession

But now i want to check file availability in bucket before start uploading

for that , i managed to get link to V2 sdk [How can I check the existence of a key/file on an Amazon S3 Bucket using AWS iOS SDK v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977483/how-can-i-check-the-existence-of-a-key-file-on-an-amazon-s3-bucket-using-aws-ios)

what is the link used in V1 ??

Answer (score 1):

AWS SDK for iOS is depreciated now; so I believe the documentation link also must have been taken out.

> Version 1 of the AWS Mobile SDK is deprecated as of September 29, 2014
>   and will continue to be available until December 31, 2014. If you are
>   building new apps, we recommend you use Version 2. If you are working
>   on existing apps that use Version 1 (1.7.x or lower) of the AWS Mobile
>   SDK, you can download v1 for Android here and iOS here. The API
>   reference guides are included in the respective downloads. Apps built
>   using Version 1 will continue to function after December 31, 2014.
>   However, we highly recommend that you update your apps to the latest
>   version so you can take advantage of the latest features and bug
>   fixes.
>   **Source** : http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/

I managed to find a sample code from AWS Mobile Blog [http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx15F6J3B8B4YKK/Creating-Mobile-Apps-with-Dynamic-Content-Stored-in-Amazon-S3] to get the S3 object, you can extrapolate from there.

```
-(void)getRemoteImage:(AmazonS3Client*)s3
             withName:(NSString*)imageName
           fromBucket:(NSString*)bucketName
{
    S3GetObjectRequest *request = 
       [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:imageName withBucket:bucketName];
    S3GetObjectResponse *response = [s3 getObject:request];

    [self storeImageLocally:response.body withName:imageName];
}
```

Download Link for v1 iOS SDK : http://sdk-for-ios.amazonwebservices.com/aws-ios-sdk-1.7.1.zip

Comment: thank you for the reply , but this gives me a runtime exception since file might not have saved  in s3 bucket ,

Comment: exception AmazonServiceException { RequestId:E128351E5CB99880, ErrorCode:NoSuchKey, Message:The specified key does not exist. }

Comment: so handle this exception; this indicates that the S3 file doesn't exits.

Comment: Thanks for the links @Naveen. Even thought 1.7.1 is depreciated but sometime old apps need it. That links helped.